# Cloud Dataflow Errors in Persisting to BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

We have a batch cloud dataflow pipeline job running for a long time and suddenly it started failing.
Generally based on amount of data and historical jobs ran, it finishes in under `~10` minutes but lately it started taking `~8` hours and never gets finished and threw lots of errors.

Basically Structure of Pipeline is

> Read From BigQuery -> Locate DATA in GCS -> Do some processing ->
> Write data to BigQuery in other table in other project.

One of the error i am seeing is

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Errors found while processing rows. Please refer to the row_errors field for details. The list may not be complete because of the size limitations. Entity: projects/test123-development/datasets/datasetmy/tables/extract979_cknkc_failure/streams/Cic2NTM3NDA3NS0wMDAwLTJiMDQtODczMC1kNGY1NDdlNjZjNDQ6czI
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.RetryManager.await(RetryManager.java:270)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.RetryManager.run(RetryManager.java:250)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.StorageApiWriteUnshardedRecords$WriteRecordsDoFn.flushAll(StorageApiWriteUnshardedRecords.java:435)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.StorageApiWriteUnshardedRecords$WriteRecordsDoFn.finishBundle(StorageApiWriteUnshardedRecords.java:495)
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Errors found while processing rows. Please refer to the row_errors field for details. The list may not be complete because of the size limitations. Entity: projects/test123-development/datasets/datasetmy/tables/extract979_cknkc_failure/streams/Cic2NTM3NDA3NS0wMDAwLTJiMDQtODczMC1kNGY1NDdlNjZjNDQ6czI
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1.StreamWriter.requestCallback(StreamWriter.java:574)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1.StreamWriter.access$1000(StreamWriter.java:49)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1.StreamWriter$2.run(StreamWriter.java:225)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1.StreamConnection$1.onResponse(StreamConnection.java:63)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1.StreamConnection$1.onResponse(StreamConnection.java:54)
    at com.google.api.gax.tracing.TracedResponseObserver.onResponse(TracedResponseObserver.java:90)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ExceptionResponseObserver.onResponseImpl(ExceptionResponseObserver.java:74)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.StateCheckingResponseObserver.onResponse(StateCheckingResponseObserver.java:62)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcDirectStreamController$ResponseObserverAdapter.onMessage(GrpcDirectStreamController.java:134)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onMessage(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:33)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onMessage(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:33)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onMessage(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:33)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.onMessage(DelayedClientCall.java:447)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1MessagesAvailable.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:661)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1MessagesAvailable.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:646)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

I don't get `Please refer to the row_errors field for details`. where can I find `row_errors` or enable them ?

I tried to run same pipeline locally and it worked fine.

I am writing to BigQuery using following method

```
    public static BigQueryIO.Write<TestClass> write() {
        return BigQueryIO.<TestClass>write()
                         .to(tableName)
                         .withFormatFunction(TestClass::toTableRow)
                         .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
                         .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
                         .withFailedInsertRetryPolicy(InsertRetryPolicy.alwaysRetry())
                         .withMethod(BigQueryIO.Write.Method.STORAGE_WRITE_API);
    }
```

Let me know if any additional details are required to investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

The error is not self explanatory and lacks contextual information. It is also hard to get exact details of `row_errors` field but I realised that I was writing to two tables(success and failure tables) and one of table's generated schema was wrong in the custom dataflow job that we'd written.

Updated the schema to match the target table and it worked.

Also I came across this github link after deep searching which resembles to similar thoughts.

> When the error content contains the following text:
>
> INVALID_ARGUMENT: Errors found while processing rows. Please refer to
> the row_errors field for details. The list may not be complete because
> of the size limitations. Entity:

> First: check whether the 'existing
> data processing' strategy of the target table maintains the original
> structure of the target table;
>
> Second: Check the generated table model;
>
> Third: Check whether the table exists in BigQuery and check the table
> structure;
>
> Fourth: check whether the table model generated by the task is
> consistent with the table structure of the table with the same name
> that exists in BigQuery, including fields and field types;
>
> Fifth: In case of inconsistency, in order to avoid the problems caused
> by the inconsistency between the newly generated model and the target
> end table with the same name, it is recommended to change the
> 'processed data' strategy to 'clear the target end table structure and
> data'.

Reference : https://github.com/tapdata/tapdata/blob/3a10551b1eb27e977afe61af0924f172916eace4/connectors/bigquery-connector/src/main/resources/docs/bigquery_en_US.md